# Programmatically adding hibernate interceptor in JpaProperties - Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, interceptor

I'm writing a library with spring boot, and I need to programmatically insert a hibernate interceptor through it (because I can't use a `.properties` in a lib).

I want to avoid providing my own `sessionFactory` bean, I think it would be good to leave that possibility to an implementing project, also saves me from manually scanning for entities.

My <s>dumb</s> idea was that I could "inject" my interceptor into the `JpaProperties`. That didn't work at all, it ran the `@PostConstruct` but nothing changed. I had a feeling this wouldn't work, but I would like to understand why, and how I may get this to work.

```java
@Autowired private JpaProperties properties;
@Autowired private MyInterceptor myInterceptor; //yep a bean

@PostConstruct public void add() {
    ((Map) properties.getProperties())
            .put(
                    "hibernate.session_factory.interceptor",
                    myInterceptor
            );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this is using an `@PostConstruct` annotation, the addition to the `JpaProperties` will only occur after the `EntityManagerFactoryBuilder` has been created in `JpaBaseConfiguration`. This means that changes to the property map will not be present in the builder after this point.

To customize the `JpaProperties`, you should instantiate a bean which adds your configuration in, like:

```
    @Primary
    @Bean
    public JpaProperties jpaProperties() {
        JpaProperties properties = new JpaProperties();
        properties.getProperties().put("hibernate.session_factory.interceptor", myInterceptor);
        return properties;
    }
```

This will then be injected into `HibernateJpaConfiguration` and used when constructing the `EntityManagerFactoryBuilder`.

Comment: Providing my own bean won't override all configurations in the .properties file? My intent is only to override `hibernate.session_factory.interceptor`.

Comment: Constructing your own JpaProperties object will not override configuration values in .properties file or other property sources. When the JpaProperties object is configured, the `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.jpa")` annotation on the object causes any property with a key such as `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size` to be inserted into the property map without the `spring.jpa.properties` prefix.

Comment: then this solves a 2 day old headache... thank you!